# struggling with creating Insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

I create `Insert` statement for `organization` table like this:

```
select'Insert into Organizations(Name,ContactPerson,ContactNumber,Mobilenumber)values('''+Nameofthecompany+''+','+Nameofthepersonresponsibleforrecruitment+','+PhoneNumber+','+MobileNumber+''')' from Organization
```

When I execute this statement I get insert statement. But the issue is where the value is null, it shows all columns `null`.

**Example:** (in database)

- Name: xxxx
- ContactPerson: zzzz
- ContactNumber:444444
- MobileNumber: null

so my insert statement looks like:

```
Null.
```

I want only that column provide null. other details showing properly. Is there any way in sql server? Help me anyone...

Comment: Just use parameters and all of this goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of concatenating anything to NULL, even itself, is always NULL. Workaround with ISNULL function:

```
select'Insert into Organizations(Name,ContactPerson,ContactNumber,Mobilenumber)
values('''+ISNULL(Nameofthecompany, 'NULL')+''+','
          +ISNULL(Nameofthepersonresponsibleforrecruitment, 'NULL')+','
          +ISNULL(PhoneNumber, 'NULL')+','
          +ISNULL(MobileNumber, 'NULL')+''')' 
from Organization
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00dfc/1)

Comment: Note: this handles the NULLs but doesn't quote the strings.  See my answer below, which does both.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - just use `ISNULL(..)` to turn a `NULL` into e.g. an empty string:

```
SELECT 
    'INSERT INTO Organizations(Name, ContactPerson, ContactNumber, Mobilenumber) VALUES(''' + 
    ISNULL(Nameofthecompany, '') + '' + ',' + 
    ISNULL(Nameofthepersonresponsibleforrecruitment, '') + ',' + 
    ISNULL(PhoneNumber, '') + ',' + ISNULL(MobileNumber,'') + ''')' 
FROM Organization
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding each of the parameters to the SQL statement, you need to check whether they're null, and if so use the keyword NULL, otherwise include a literal string surrounded with single quotes, but bearing in mind that if the string contains any single quotes, they need to be replaced with two single quotes.

Update the SQL for each parameter something like the following:

```
CASE WHEN MobileNumber IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '''' + REPLACE(MobileNumber, '''', '''''') + '''' END
```

Comment: I have nearly more than 5000 records. All fields somewhere else got Null value.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment.  If you handle the NULLs correctly for each parameter in your SQL statement, it will cope with 5000 records as easily as it will cope with 1 record.

Comment: what i tried to say means, I have fields like OrganName, Address, PhoneNo. My values are like xxx,dkfjds,111111111 like that. So this record not contains Null value. so it has no pblm. Another record, yyy,Null,444444 like that. So i get result "Null" only. Other two values are not showing. This is the issue and solved also.